# Add span tag with javascript function to html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function in javascript to change the background color of some cells in a html table

```
<script language="javascript">
function GetAllValues() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById("monitor");
        for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++){
                if (parseInt(tbl.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML) == 1){
                         tbl.rows[i].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }else if (parseInt(tbl.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML) == 2){
                        tbl.rows[i].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }else if (parseInt(tbl.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML) == 3){
                        tbl.rows[i].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }else if (parseInt(tbl.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML) == 5){
                        tbl.rows[i].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
                }else{
                        tbl.rows[i].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "white";
                        }
</script>
```

But I need to add an "span" tag to the value of the cell like this:

```
<span class="label label-success">table cell value</span>
```

I don't know how to add this tag into the cell.

Can you bring me some snippet or a link where I can take some ideas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the innerHTML to the current innerHTML value wrapped with the span tags by concatenating them.

```
tbl.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML = '<span>' + tbl.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML + '</span>'
```